# Can i trust Microsoft BackgroundService to be always alive?

Tags: signalr, blazor, blazor-server-side, signalr-hub, kestrel-http-server

I am building a multiplayer video game with blazor.

This game is very basic and will be playable through a web browser.
The hard work is for making possible real time communication between players. I used to work with socketservers like red5 in the past.

Today, i want to build this video game with Microsoft tools: Blazor and signalr.

My problem is i need some threads on server side. This threads will manage game logic. I have tried to create a BackgroundService Task. It works fine. I can communicate with players through signalr hub. But i am scared about something on BackgroundService's: They are attached to http server process. Sometimes IIS kills and create new processes. So how can i be sure my BackgroundService will always be alive ? (even if no player is connected, at night for example). How can i be sure my BackgroundService won't be killed and re-created by IIS ?

I have tried to work with kestrel web server and put it behing an nginx proxy. My BackgroundService is never killed. But i am wondering if kestrel is designed to handle a lot of web clients at the same time...

Are there alternatives to BackgroundService object ? I have think to create a separate program but i prefer a monolithic approach...

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your web app will automatically be restarted if that is what you are asking. The only time when it restarts is if you deploy or if you manually restart or stop/start. So I think it's safe to use background services for light workloads.

But if you plan to have any kind of scaling, I suggest you look into [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

Comment: The load on the background service will be very low. But i will have a high load on web server. Do you think i can work with kestrel ? Thanks

Comment: As far as I know kestrel is pretty sleek. We used it at my previous company to handle some pretty high throughput, so I'd say you're safe.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @tiny town software. Did you put kestrel behind an nginx proxy or something like that ? Did you have to do some performance tuning on kestrel itself ? Thanks

Comment: I personally wasn't involved in building that up, but yes we used nginx. I am not sure about performance tuning. I suggest you get it to work and see how it performs out of the box and then adjust as needed.